# Change view with AlertAction

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to change of ViewController when I click on "OK" button of my `AlertAction` but I have an error

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT "Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'NextQuestion'

Here is my code : [Code on error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NC3E.png)

Can you help me please ? If you want more codes, don't hesitate. :)

Thanks !

Comment: You should show the storyboard, maybe you forgot to give the identifier to the segue

Comment: Don't post your code as an image. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a segue from your current vc to the destination one and name it **NextQuestion**

[image]

Comment: What I want to do is refresh the page but when I apply the function loadView, the view is reloaded but the code does not start.

Comment: you want to reload the current VC when you click ok in alert ?? what's your hierarchy

Comment: Yes, because my actually view is a quiz game and for have an other question, I want to reload current VC. You think I should do otherwise?

Comment: why can't you easily cut  the code you set question and answers in a function and call it again with a new index instead of reload ??